# How to make a parameter from a Route optional with React-Router 3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I visit example.com/crud/4 it's ok, but not when I hit example.com/crud. How to make the `id` param as optional?

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './index.js';

function errorLoading(err) {
  console.log('Dynamic page loading failed! Error: ' + err);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

const routes = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard/crud/:id',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./entries/crud')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    }

  ]
};

export default () => <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />;
```

I'm using react router 3.

Answer (score 2):

To make any `params` optional you need to use `(/:param_name)`, it will be considered as optional, try this:

```
path: 'dashboard/crud(/:id)',
```

**Update**:

To render different component on the basic of params values, you need to write a separate wrapper component, pass the `params` it that file, on the basic of `params` value return the component, like this:

```
export default class Wrapper extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let params = this.props.params.id;
        if(params == 'view') return <A/>;
        else if(params == 'edit') return <B/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about 2 param? like crud/view and crud/edit can load different component.

Comment: You need two different routes for that

Comment: This worked when I hit example.com/crud/5 but not when I click on a Link, my code for Link component is <Link to={"crud/" + item.id}>

Comment: ok have to specified absolute path. like <Link to={"/something/else/crud/" + item.id}>